# jQuery date picker not closing on outside click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a jquery date picker that opens when clicking on a icon. The date picker is opening correctly and the logic is also happening correctly. I'm facing an issue where the date picker is not closing when clicking outside (or losing focus). How can i close the datepicker when clicking outside?

The code is like this

```
<i class="fad fa-calendar-week" id="edit-checkin-date" onclick="editCheckoutDates();"></i>
```

the function

```
function editCheckoutDates(){
  jQuery(function ($) {
  jQuery("#edit-checkin-date")
  .datepicker({
    language: "en",
    range: true,
    dateFormat: "M d",
    multipleDatesSeparator: " - ",
    minDate: from_min_date,
    maxDate: to_max_date,
    onSelect: function(formattedDate, date, inst) {
      if (date[0]) {  
        $("#from").val(
          ("0" + (date[0].getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
          "/" + //month
          ("0" + date[0].getDate()).slice(-2) +
          "/" + //day
            date[0].getFullYear()
        ); //year);
      }
      if (date[1]) {
        $("#to").val(
          ("0" + (date[1].getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
          "/" + //month
          ("0" + date[1].getDate()).slice(-2) +
          "/" + //day
            date[1].getFullYear()
        ); //year);
      }

      if (2 !== date.length) return;

    }
  });
});
}
```

Here the date picker is opening when clicking on the icon stated above. But the issue is when clicking outside the date picker does not close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this,

```
$("#edit-checkin-date").on("blur", function(e) { $(this).datepicker("hide"); });
```